# d3 SVG components not showing up in Chrome

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying out D3 for fun and for some reason, I cannot get my svg components to render in the browser. Inspecting the console, I can see the svg container was created but no elements were created.

I am loading from a .json file. If I print the data to the console, I can see everything contained in the .json file so it is getting the correct data.

My HTML is pretty basic:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>D3 Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3-min.js"></script>            
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tree"></div>
    <script>
        importJsonData();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my JS:

```
function importJsonData() {
    d3.json("./test/test_data.json", function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        let canvas = d3.select("#tree").append("svg")
            .attr("width", 1000)
            .attr("height", 700)

        canvas.selectAll("rect")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("width", 50)
        .attr("height", 50)
        .attr("y", function (d, i)
        {
            return i * 50
        })
        .attr("fill", "green");
    });
}
```

I might have the wrong understanding of selectAll - I thought it would selectAll elements matching a filter but if you attribute the data to this with enter() it will create a component for each element.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error that needs to be fixed first, no SVG at all appended

```
.attr("width", "50)
```

Should be

```
.attr("width", 50)
```

```js
var data = [{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}];
drawData(data);

function drawData(data) {
    console.log(data);
    let canvas = d3.select("#tree").append("svg")
        .attr("width", 1000)
        .attr("height", 700)

    canvas.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", 50)
    .attr("height", 50)
    .attr("y", function (d, i) { return i * 50; })
    .attr("fill", "green");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<div id="tree"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping to get the data from the file being read and not a hard-coded array.

Comment: @Darnold14 For the sake of your problem it does not matter where the data comes from. rioV8 just made the effort to put this into a [mcve] for you to show it is working. The essence of this answer is covered by its first 4 lines: remove the quotation mark and you are done.

Comment: @altocumulus: I'm curious about all the other requirements he will have and what the deadline of the assignment is.